Power BI Embedded Continuously Loading with CSP Error in Laravel Application
enter image description here
I'm working on embedding a Power BI report in a Laravel-based web application using the Power BI REST API and an access token for authentication. However, when I attempt to render the report in the browser, it never finishes loading and continuously displays the Power BI logo. Inspecting the network tab in the browser's developer tools reveals an error related to the Content Security Policy (CSP).
In network error showing (Power BI loading The sandbox is too restrictive and preventing correct functioning).
I want to get the analytics report from Power BI using the get report API against an access token that I'm generating from an Oauth Azure registered application, and against that access token, I want to call the Power BI get report API and get the response with an embed link, then render the Power BI report in different browsers, but it keeps loading with the Power BI logo.
The expected result is that a report should be rendered because I'm getting an embed link of the report.
